# my project has diffrent result every time

Tags: c, fatal-error

I wrote this code in my project but every time i run it the answer is diffrent.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKfrk.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code inside the question itself, copy-pasted as text. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You have hidden your code well

Comment: what is `varubale`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize sum with a value of 0. The reason it is different every time is you are calling sum which you never assigned a value. Anything could be in memory where sum is stored, which is why your results are inconsistent.